# How to exit from script using if else

Tags: if-statement, exit, wsh, jscript

Please, tell me how to exit from javascript (i run it on harddrive) when i use if statement. The follow code doesn't work:

```
if (fso.FileExists("C:\\EXT\\file.txt") ) //check if there file in the folder
            {
    log.WriteLine(file_exist_time + " - file exists C:\\EXT\\ "); 
            }
    else 
            {  
            log.WriteLine("There is no file in C:\\EXT\\"); 

                             function exit ()
                                    {
                                throw ('Script Exit');
                                    }

        }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just do the `throw` directly after the log call? Right now you just define a function named `exit` but you never call it.

Comment: throw('Exit') doesn't work. =(

Comment: "Return" doesn't work too: function exit ()
                                    {
                                return;
                                    }

Comment: This looks like VBscript rather than Javascript. `Exit Function` should exit the function early.

Comment: If you put `return` in a function, it only returns from _that_ function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`WScript.Quit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0fx1aw%28VS.84%29.aspx) to completely exit the script.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a function definition here? You're not even calling the function. You can simply do this:

```
if (fso.FileExists("C:\\EXT\\file.txt")){ //check if there file in the folder
  log.WriteLine(file_exist_time + " - file exists C:\\EXT\\ ");
}
else{
  log.WriteLine("There is no file in C:\\EXT\\");
  throw('Script Exit');
}
```

However, `throw` alone doesn't stop the function execution, it only moves it to your `catch`-statement. Read more about [exception handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (fso.FileExists("C:\\EXT\\file.txt") ) //check if there file in the folder
{
    log.WriteLine(file_exist_time + " - file exists C:\\EXT\\ "); 
}
else 
{  
    log.WriteLine("There is no file in C:\\EXT\\"); 
    return;
    // Or possibly throw("Exit");
}
```

In other words, don't put the `throw` or `return` in a separate function, especially if you don't call that function.

Comment: return and throw("Exit") does not work. it works: else {  
            log.WriteLine("There is no file in C:\\EXT\\"); 
   break top;
   
     }